# Node editor connections are not curvy

Tags: node-editor

I'm using Blender 2.81. I tried reinstalling the Node Wrangler extension multiple times. Everything works fine, but it only displayed those bendy/curvy connections/links following the first install after a fresh setup of Blender 2.81.

I couldn't find any option to fix this in the preferences.

Answer (score 2):

As I was throughly looking through preferences one last time lest I post a stupid question, it appears that the option is not related to node wrangler alone: it's a theme option for all node editors called "**Noodle curving**".

So links are really called **noodles**.

[image: Noodle Curving and node editor]

Comment: so maybe explain more clearly how to set it   ;)